# Even, Odd with min and max for the Odd only

Tags: java

Prompt the user to enter the size of an array and allow the user to 
input integer values to your array. Check each element if it is even
or odd. If even, print solved elemets (ascending order), If odd, get
the max and min using conditional statement. Output the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int s[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int e = sc.nextInt();
        s[i] = e;
    }

    Arrays.sort(s);
    System.out.println("\nEven numbers in ascending order:");
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

        if (s[j] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(s[j] + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nOdd numbers in descending order:");
    for(int j = (n -1); j >= 0; j--) {
        if (s[j] % 2 == 1) {
            System.out.print(s[j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to add min/max for the Odd

Comment: So far I have the code for min/max but I am confused on how to add it to my current code for odd/even

Comment: Could you show us your attempt(s) at adding the min/max code to the odd/even code?

Comment: Just make two different array one for odd element other for even and find max/min value using newly created array.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you could try this:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // init min to the most max value
int max = 0; // store max value
for(int j = (n -1); j >= 0; j--) {
    if (s[j] % 2 == 1) {
        if (min > s[j]) {
            min = s[j];
        }
        if (max < s[j]) {
            max = s[j];
        }
        System.out.print(s[j] + " ");
    }
}
System.out.println("min = " + min);
System.out.println("max = " + max);
```

Full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int s[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int e = sc.nextInt();
        s[i] = e;
    }

    Arrays.sort(s);
    System.out.println("\nEven numbers in ascending order:");
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

        if (s[j] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(s[j] + " ");
        }
    }

    //===========================================
    System.out.println("\nOdd numbers in descending order:");
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // init min to the most max value
    int max = 0; // store max value
    for(int j = (n -1); j >= 0; j--) {
        if (s[j] % 2 == 1) {
            if (min > s[j]) {
                min = s[j];
            }
            if (max < s[j]) {
                max = s[j];
            }
            System.out.print(s[j] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(); // for new line
    System.out.println("min = " + min);
    System.out.println("max = " + max);
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how can I add this code to my current code for even/odd? Because, in the problem it says : "If even, print solved elemets (ascending order), If odd, get
the max and min using conditional statement. Output the result."

Comment: Now the answer is updated, you can check Good Luck

Comment: I checked it, it was okay

Comment: The answer updated again you can check it,

Comment: Thanks man I will commend you.

Comment: You are welcome. And also you can edit your question instead you post it in the answer. So it is better to delete the answers which you posted for your question. By the way, if this answer was solved your problem, then accept it, to be clear for others that this question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
  System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
  int val = s.nextInt();

  if (val == 0) {
      break;
  }
  if (val < min) {
      min = val;
  }
  if (val > max) {
     max = val;
  }
}

System.out.println("min: " + min);
System.out.println("max: " + max);
```

Comment: This is not an answer, you should add this content to your question via the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35423133/edit) link. Also, please add your attempt(s) at adding the min/max code to the odd/even code? Please delete this answer after you edit your question.

Comment: I tried the above code and worked, but thanks for the help anyway